# Why is $\overline{L^\infty(\Omega)} \subset L^\infty(\Omega) $ where the closure is in norm of $L^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a domain which may or may not be unbounded (eg. $\Omega = B_1(0)\times (0,\infty)$). Why is 
$$ \overline{L^\infty(\Omega)} \subset L^\infty(\Omega)$$
 where the closure is in norm of $L^1(\Omega)$?

I would have thought that the inclusion is the other way around. Source is [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.4623.pdf), see page 11, the third displayed equation.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this is either false or trivial, or both. The closure of any subset of $X$ in $X$ is trivially a subset of $X$; just because of what the word *closure* means.  Closure is taken with respect to a particular ambient space, and cannot produce elements outside of that space.

If you meant *completion* with respect to $L^1$ norm, then the inclusion is false. The completion of $L^\infty$ with respect to $L^1$ norm can be identified with $L^1$.

So, you misunderstood something. The only conclusion from here is:

### Give the source of statements that you would like explained to you.

Comment: Thanks. Source is [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.4623.pdf), see page 11, the third displayed equation. I think what it is meant is completion wrt. the $L^1$ norm.